# Printing in C# console window

Tags: c#

I am trying to print 1820 lines in C# console window. However, when the printing is done and I view the console window, I can see only 300 lines. What is the problem here? 
When I write to file, I can see 1820 lines! So, I have narrowed down the problem to the OUTPUT console window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjust the buffer size for the window:

- Click the icon in the top-left of the window.
- Properties
- Layout
- Screen Buffer Size
- Enter the maximum value for height: 9999

If you need more than this then you need to use a GUI or write to a file and view it in a text editor.

Answer (score 7):

The standard console window in most versions of Windows have a limited buffer of lines they keep - 300 lines sounds like a reasonable buffer.

You can see (and change) that limit when you open a `cmd.exe` window and then right-click on the icon in the top left corner and choose `Properties` from the context menu:

[image]

You might be able to increase the size of that buffer to give you more lines - keep in mind that those lines will take up RAM from your system while your console window is open!

Answer (score 5):

You can use Console.SetBufferSize() to make the console buffer larger:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.SetBufferSize(Console.WindowWidth, 2000);
        // etc..
    }
}
```

--**Small Addition**--

If hoping to get the maximum possible buffer:

```
 Console.SetBufferSize(Console.WindowWidth, Int16.MaxValue-1);
```

You're not allowed anything >= Int16.MaxValue

Comment: This is actually the best answer.